# how to make rigid bodies effected by cloth?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I am trying to model a cape with a brooch. I can use the hook modifier to attach the cloth to the brooch, but the brooch isn't effected by the tension of the cloth - it just keeps falling, as if there was no cape there. Is there any way make the cloth hold the brooch in place? Is there a better way to do this entirely?

[image]

To clarify, the "brooch" object is the small oval in this gif.

Answer (score 0):

if the brooch has rigid body enabled it might be too heavy, pulling the cloth down with it. In that case you would need to either make the brooch lighter/cloth heavier or mixture of both. As well as playing around with the stiffness settings in the cloth until you get the results youre looking for.

Comment: your text "sounds" good... but for me this is not an answer. Please add a blend file or detailed steps how you would do this. And how you want to make the connection of the rigid body to the cloth. Because your solution does not work with a hook modifier....